# Sync FTP to SVN

Tags: ftp, svn

Background: there's a site which I need to edit. The only way to access files is FTP.
But since I'm not the only person who will edit it (also I'd like to have ability to roll-back and bunch of other reasons), we need version control system.

Previously (on our own server, where we have root) we used to use SVN with post-commit hook, which updated files it site's directory (site used to be on the same Linux server).

Is it possible to make post-commit hook, that uploads updated files via FTP to the remoted server? Any way to detect 'just updated' files? Maybe ready solution?

Comment: Why you discarded old workflow (from SVN to SITE over FTP)?

Comment: I don't have access to target server but FTP. Old workflow was 'SVN directly to SITE', but that was on our own server (added this to OP-post).

Comment: and **what??** You can and have to work the same way even in REPO and SITE are different hosts - you just have to `ftp` instead of `cp`. I can't see *any* research job done

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make post-commit hook, that uploads updated files via FTP to the remoted server?

Yes, it's possible

> Any way to detect 'just updated' files?

At least two (AFAICR):

- `svn log -v -q -r HEAD REPO-URL` (from any location)
- `svnlook changed REPO_PATH` (for REPO host, where REPO_PATH is local path on FS)

Well, as I can see, you must to solve two consecutive subtasks in post-commit hook (if you solve **correct task**: update site from repo, and not inverse perversion^ update repo by changed files from *some independent* location)

- build tree of files, affected in revision
- upload this tree, using pure FTP, on remote host

**Solutions for task 1**

Any of first three scripts, mentioned by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063724/960558) (other implementations may exist in wild Net also)

**Solution for task 2**

Using part of [NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) ([NcFTPPut](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html)) for uploading tree in easy one-line command

Comment: You a re correct! Thanks for response, I'll try to do this and then post about result.